# create instance in one terraform workspace

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have 2 terraform workspaces (dev and qa) and want to create an ec2 instance in the dev workspace but not in qa workspace, is their a way to do that as the module is common for both workspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple to do. The [docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces) have an example:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = "${terraform.workspace == "dev" ? 1 : 0}"
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to wrap the whole thing in `"${ }"` at this point unless you are using a really old version of Terraform.

Comment: @MarkB it's straight from the docs. feel free to open a github issue

Answer (score 1):

The terraform condition for that would look like the following:

```
count = terraform.workspace == "dev" ? 1 : 0
```